# Seeking Python solution for point, line, and poly in poly intersections

Tags: python, intersection, software-recommendations, shapely, point-in-polygon

[image: Problems I'm trying to solve]

I'm just learning Python, and I need a little direction.  I've been reading many of the posts on this site, but I haven't found one that puts me on the right path. These operations are trivial in GIS software, but I need to find a Python solution. I'm thinking the solution in in shapely, but I haven't seen any examples that I can apply. For me, all of the data are ascii files and I can parse the files into arrays, including a master polygon array with poly ID, longitude, and latitude, and other arrays for my point or line or polygon dataset. For the cases when the line or polygon intersect the master polygon new line segments or new polygons will need to be created to and will need to inherit the master polygon ID.  I'm just looking for a little guidance to put me on the best path forward.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use geopandas for that, it is very powerful and has a lot of geospatial processing possibilities. Just a small example joining points to polygon where they are intersecting (your case 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString, Polygon

# make 4 points
p1 = Point((1,1))
p2 = Point((3,3))
p3 = Point((3.5,4))
p4 = Point((6,6))

#make some polygons
polys1 = gpd.GeoSeries([Polygon([(0,0), (2,0), (2,2), (0,2)]),
                       Polygon([(2,2), (5,2), (5,4), (2,4)])])

#make dataframes
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['p1','p2','p3','p4']})
gdf1 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df1, geometry = [p1,p2,p3,p4])

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['pol1','pol2']})
gdf2 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df2, geometry =polys1)
#plot it
ax = gdf1.plot(color='red')
gdf1.plot(ax=ax, facecolor='none', edgecolor='k');
gdf2.plot(ax=ax, facecolor='none', edgecolor='k');
#spatial join
joined = gpd.sjoin(left_df=gdf2,right_df=gdf1,
               how="inner", op='intersects')
joined.head()
```

[image]

some helpful links:

- https://geopandas.readthedocs.io/en/stable/mergingdata.html
- https://atmamani.github.io/cheatsheets/open-geo/geopandas-3/